# Add ComboBox to DataGridView C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I am having some trouble adding a combobox drop down list to a row in a DataGridView, basically it never adds anything to the combobox. It draws it but it is always blank/null.

```
DataGridViewRow dr = new DataGridViewRow();
                dr.CreateCells(dataGridView1,"","","",_NewAssetDetails[0], _NewAssetDetails[1], _NewAssetDetails[2],
                                       _NewAssetDetails[3], _NewAssetDetails[4], _NewAssetDetails[5],
                                       _NewAssetDetails[6], _NewAssetDetails[7], "", _NewAssetDetails[8],
                                       "New",_NewAssetDetails[9]);
                DataGridViewComboBoxCell cb = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
                cb.Items.Add(dr.Cells[13].Value);
                if (!cb.Items.Contains("Yes"))
                    cb.Items.Add("Yes");
                if (!cb.Items.Contains("No"))
                    cb.Items.Add("No");
                if (!cb.Items.Contains("Updated"))
                    cb.Items.Add("Updated");
                dr.Cells[13] = cb;
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr);
```

The text gets added correctly but the combobox does not.
Can anyone see a problem above?

Comment: Can you try first adding the row and then `dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1].Cells[13] = cb;`

Comment: Unfortunately still no values in the combo box. The problem is that if I step through the code I can see the cell type change in the row.Cells and I can even see all the values in the combo box but it is just not showing up

Comment: I am performing that in Form1_Activated and I check if there is incoming data from a second form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have code that works for me here it is:

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(val[0], val[1], val[2], va[3], val[4]);
DataGridViewComboBoxCell cb= new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
cb.MaxDropDownItems = 5;
cb.Items.Add(DataGridView1.Rows[DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
cb.Value = DataGridView1.Rows[DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
DataGridView1.Rows[DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[3] = cb;
```

Comment: Hmm I have added `dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[13].Value = "New";` and that seems to have fixed it. Thanks.